# viewpager with retained fragment in tabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I searched about retaining Fragments in an Activity, but I need to know how to use retained Fragments in View Pager.
I found [this](http://www.bernie-eng.com/blog/2013/01/23/retaining-fragments-in-viewpagers/), but since it doesn't have complete code I couldn't understand it.
Could anyone address me a complete example or tutorial about using ViewPager with retained Fragment?

Comment: By retaining you want all pages to be created when the ViewPager was created. Not each time?

Comment: Your link is not working on mine.